# GTK Message Dialog Drag and Drop

Tags: c++, gtk

I need to make just a simple gtk message dialog with one OK button and no more interaction. So i have created it as follows:

```
    widgetInfoDialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(
    NULL,
    GtkDialogFlags(GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT),
    GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
    GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
    "%s",
    sInfoTitle);
```

As it is modal, it does not let the interaction with the main window, however it lets the user to drag the text inside the dialog and drop it in some text area of the main window, like the ones i attach in the picture below.

Would it be possible to avoid this drag and drop interaction?

Besides i woud like to remove the close and minimize buttons!

Thank you in advance![image]

Comment: I consider it as an advantage that texts of message dialogs can be copy/pasted. (This is helpful to cite messages correctly for support requests.) If you don't want to accept drop messages in the main window you should configure the concerning widgets not to accept drop events. (IMHO)

Comment: ok! thanks for the help. I have solved it with the drop event. Would you know if it is possible to erase the close and minimize buttons from the dialog bar?

Comment: I wouldn't remove the close button but let it act like the OK button.
Concerning the minimize button, I found: [Re: GTK remove minimize & maximize buttons](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2004-December/msg00368.html). In general, frame and title bar are subject of the Window Manager. Thus, tweaking it in GTK+ (which is not really Window Manager aware) may work only partially. On the other hand, the Window Manager is the user's choice. So, whatever it provides might be the user intention - no need to care too much on developer side. ;-)